# Generating short encoded string from an array of values

Tags: php, laravel

I have a set of 5 dynamic IDs that I want to encode as one single ID and pass it around as GET parameter. What I'm doing now is basically:

```
$ids = [
  'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
  'country_id' => $request->get('country_id'),
  'type_id' => 1,
  'some_other_id' => $request->get('some_other_id'),
  'something_else' => 2,
];

$encoded_id = Cypher::encodeString(json_encode($ids));

return redirect()->away("https://somedomain.com/?id=$encoded_id");
```

And later on when I receive a request, I can decode it:

```
try {
  $ids = Cypher::decodeString($request->get('id'));
  echo $ids['country_id'];
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that the output encoded string has 304 characters, so it might happen that the URL will be too long:

```
https://somedomain.com/?id=eyJpdiI6Ilk0YkVOSUFqUPJLZ1ZGcXNPY8pkOXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieGFVUlNFdlNGSk1wWm1BcE5HREZTMHhxNnZMVktDZ0dCR1RQSk9vZnFASTJTZjZtUGg5cFFtK2FXTCtxOFNlMVM1MU8yTVpyN1wvTFJNNDF1Q1F0Zlwvd0JzaWFCR2NWbTJkM3dxUGtqR21Kcz0iAwJtYWMiOiJlMzdjOWU4NzBjNGI0MGNlNzA1NzVjZWY2ZDI3YWQ0MmMxOWJkOWI4MTQwOGQ5ODc3OTBjMzUwMzViZWY2YjMwIn0=
```

What I'd like to achieve is something shorter like:

```
https://somedomain.com/?id=eyJpdiI6Ilk0YkVOSUFqUPJLZ1ZGcXNPY8pkOXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieGFVUlN
```

Which I could decode easily.

I don't really care about heavy security here, it's just few IDs which will be there. More important for me is the "user-friendly" encoded string, and ability to encode/decode it quickly. I was thinking about creating a hash map, but there will be way too many data for that. How can I do it?

Comment: You can store encoded ids and corresponding 4 to 5 digit encoded code in your database and then you can use that 4 to 5 encoded code in url to access those ids.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simply using `base64_encode` and `base64_decode`:

```
$ids = [
  'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
  'country_id' => $request->get('country_id'),
  'type_id' => 1,
  'some_other_id' => $request->get('some_other_id'),
  'something_else' => 2,
];

$encoded_id = base64_encode(implode(',', $ids));
```

Then to decode:

```
$ids = explode(',', base64_decode($encoded_id));
```

I've tested in on https://www.base64encode.org/, and string `11111,2222,33333,44444,55555` turns into `MTExMTEsMjIyMiwzMzMzMyw0NDQ0NCw1NTU1NQ==`, which is 40 characters long.